# C++ copy list of chars to string exactly without ignoring multiple whitespace

Tags: c++, string, list, char, whitespace

I have a list of chars, L:

```
{'h','e','l','l','o',' ', ' ',' ', 'm', 'y', ' ', ' ',' ', 'n','a','m','e'};
```

I want to copy it to a string. I want to maintain triple spaces and get a string S below:

```
"hello   my   name"
```

I tried this:

```
string S(L.begin(), L.end());
```

but it somehow removes triple spaces and gives me single spaces and S becomes: "hello my name".
I tried iterating one by one:

```
string S = "";
for (auto it = L.begin(); it!=L.end(); it++){
   S+=*it;
}
```

I still get "hello my name" with single spaces.
I tried storing the list in a vector of chars and then turning into a string by looping through vector and pushing back into string one by one and still it ignores multiple spaces. How do I tell the computer to copy the characters of a list to a string verbatim, regardless of how many consecutive whitespace characters there are. Even if it is just a list of spaces, I'd like to get a string of spaces. Any help?

See my code below:

```
int main() {
    list<char> L {'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'm', 'y', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'n', 'a', 'm', 'e'};

    string S_attempt1(L.begin(), L.end());

    string S_attempt2 = "";
    for (auto it = L.begin(); it != L.end(); it++){
        S_attempt2+=*it;
    }

    cout << S_attempt1 << endl;
    cout << S_attempt2 << endl;
}
```

For some the strings I get are `"hello my name"` instead of `"hello   my   name"`

Comment: your list include spaces ' ' like this.  first , you should remove spaces from your list.

Comment: What do you mean by "List of chars". Is it an `array`? That doesn't have `.begin()`, and `.end()` members. Please show a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Show the declaration of `L` and show the method you're using to verify that it's removing spaces. Are you viewing it in your debugger? Printing it out? We need a [example].

Comment: [This works](https://godbolt.org/z/22rvxS) with a suitably declared `L`. You’ve made an error elsewhere.

Comment: *I have a list of chars, L*  --  *tried storing the list* -- *How do I tell the computer to copy the characters of a list* -- What is this "list"?  Unless you mean `std::list`, there is no such thing as "list" in standard C++.

Comment: Yes, the list is `std::list<char> L;`

Comment: Thanks all. I've edited the original post and added clarifications. I tried running the same code on a different IDE and it works ok. What could be causing this?

Comment: The terminal display settings may be messed up. Your code works: https://godbolt.org/z/NffWUD . If you copy the output when it looks like it has only one space and paste it into your editor, you should hopefully see the correct number of spaces.

Comment: Incidentally, don’t use `std::list`. It’s *almost never* the correct type. Even for relatively frequent insertions and deletions (where linked lists theoretically outperform contiguous sequence types), `std::vector` outperforms `std::list` in almost all practical applications on modern hardware, due to cache locality effects.

Comment: @Justin, Thank you that was apparently the problem. It was making the right string but the debugger was just displaying it wrong! Thanks!

Comment: @KonradRudolph, good to know! Thanks for the advice on std::vector vs std::list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work fine and doesn't ignore the spaces:

```
string convertToString(list<char> lst, int size) 
{ 
    string s = ""; 
    for (auto const& i : lst) {
        s = s + i;
    }
    return s; 
}
```

Running this like...

```
list<char> L = {'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'm', 'y', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'n', 'a', 'm', 'e'}; 
int L_size = sizeof(L) / sizeof(char); 
string s_L = convertToString(L, L_size);
cout << s_L << endl;
```

...returns the expected output.